# Why doesn't std::weak_ptr have operator->?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, weak-ptr

It could be implemented thusly:

```
  std::shared_ptr<T> operator->() {
      auto shared = lock();
      if(shared == nullptr) {
          throw std::bad_weak_ptr(); // or some other exception
      }
      return shared;
  }
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e903500841c9313)

*Why did the **authors** of weak_ptr decide to not have operator->?* (They must have thought of it)

I can think of potential reasons but I wonder what the **official reason** is, if one exists. Potential reasons:

- Discourage extra increment/decrement of reference count for multiple calls
- Encourage explicit locking rather than (somewhat hidden) exceptions

If you are confused about the lifetime of the returned shared_ptr, see [this paper.](http://www.stroustrup.com/wrapper.pdf)

Also, someone asked why would one use a weak_ptr if you expect it to not be expired? Answer: cycles.

Answer (score 10):

The [original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2003/n1450.html) `weak_ptr` didn't include an overload of `operator->`.

I haven't looked through the minutes of every meeting since, but have followed what's been discussed, and don't recall a mention of anybody having proposed that it should be added. As such, the "official" reason it's not present is probably largely that nobody's proposed that it be added.

If you want to go back to the *very* beginning, most of this stems from John Ellis and David Detlef's [Safe, Efficient Garbage Collection for C++](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/c++94/full_papers/ellis.a) paper, from Usenix 1994. That included a `weakptr` type in its Appendix B. That's somewhat different (`weakptr::pointer` returns a pointer directly, or a null-pointer if the pointee has already been destroyed), but still didn't use an operator overload to do the job.

Greg Colvin wrote the [original proposal to add `counted_ptr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1994/N0555.pdf) to the standard. Its `counted_ptr` was essentially equivalent to what's now called `shared_ptr`, but did not include anything analogous to `weak_ptr`.

Shortly after the committee rejected the `counted_ptr` proposal and adopted `auto_ptr` instead, the basic idea of `counted_ptr` was revived on Boost. I don't remember seeing any discussion of adding an `operator->` to it, but it "lived" there for so long that it's entirely possible somebody could have proposed it without my being aware of it.

Comment: But as far as I can see, the proposed `operator->` does exactly what you describe: convert to `shared_ptr`, and only allow access to the object if that succeeds (throwing otherwise). How is that a bad thing?

Comment: @MikeSeymour: You want to keep the shared_ptr around and call methods on it, without having to pay the synchronization cost.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: Sometimes you do, in which case manual conversion is still available. Sometimes you just want to access a single member, in which case manual conversion is just noise, which the proposed operator can make neater.

Comment: [even further back](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) the oldest boost docs for `weak_ptr` I could find easily: Feb 10 2003.  No `operator->` here either.  Copywrite claims include "Copyright 1999 Greg Colvin and Beman Dawes. Copyright 2002 Darin Adler. Copyright 2002, 2003 Peter Dimov" which line up with the authors of the original proposal you link. [here](http://www.boost.org/users/history/old_versions.html) are fragments of older docs, 1999 mention of smart pointer. [Version 1.20](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.20.2/) may enlighten?

Comment: Ah, boost version 1.20 has a shared pointer, but no weak pointer at first glance.  So we can find the first version where weak pointer was added to boost.  And the above demonstrates that `std::shared_ptr` came from boost (the authors of the proposal, and the paper itself).

Answer (score 7):

I'll take a shot at giving a good reason why this is not a good idea:

One thing is clarity:

```
ptr->foo();
ptr->bar();
```

The problem here is that somewhere between the first and second call, ptr might expire, either by a different thread (which would be a race condition) or by a sideeffect of the call to `foo`.

Another thing is symmetry: When I have a pointer, I expect operators `*`, `->` and an implicit conversion to a boolean value. Some might disagree, but operators `*` and `->` often coincide. I'd be surprised that this isn't the case here.

That said, with C++11, it's just too easy to write:

```
if (auto p = ptr.lock()) {
    p->foo();
    p->bar();
}
```

Knowing that `ptr` is a `weak_ptr`, the meaning and behaviour of that code is pretty clear.

Comment: After asking around more, I think you're right about symmetry. Having operator-> would make weak_ptr seem more like an actual pointer when it lacks the most basic operator*.

Comment: It also occurred to me that this is a good reason. In short, weak_ptr is not a pointer, so it shouldn't have to behave like one. Maybe weak_ref would have been a better choice, but the term reference is taken, too.